# py2neo 2.0: ERROR:httpstream:! SocketError: timed out

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I execute a long running (5 mintues) Cypher query with py2neo 2.0:

`graph.cypher.run(query)` or `result = graph.cypher.execute(query)`

The query fails after ~60 sec with a Socket Error from httpstream:

`ERROR:httpstream:! SocketError: timed out`

The same happens when I use a Cypher transaction. This did not happen with the same query and py2neo 1.6.4. Can I increase the time py2neo waits for a response? I didn't find anything in the docs.

---

**Update**

I found a hard coded `socket_timeout` in `py2neo.packages.httpstream.http`. Setting it to a higher value avoids the SocketError:

```
from py2neo.packages.httpstream import http
http.socket_timeout = 9999

result = graph.cypher.execute("MATCH (g:Gene) RETURN count(g)")
```

Can I somehow set the timeout for a single query?

Comment: Can you change this setting somewhere in neo4j's files (outside of the script)? Like in one of the files in the conf folder?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's currently no way to adjust the timeout for individual queries as this setting applies at a connection level and one connection can obviously be used for many queries. The `socket_timeout` you're using *is* the correct way to adjust the timeout globally though.